# Unexpected argument grid_dist_x using PDAL

Tags: dem, lidar, las, multi-band, pdal

I'm trying to convert a .las file to a DTM/DEM using PDAL, but having the issue of multiple bands instead of one.

I went through [Generating a DTM](https://www.pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/dtm/dtm.html) and [writers.gdal](https://www.pdal.io/stages/writers.gdal.html) but it prompts an error message:

> Unexpected argument 'grid_dist_x'.

```
{
    "pipeline": [
       "E:/ground.laz",
        {
            "filename": "E:/ground.tif",
            "grid_dist_x": "2.0",
            "grid_dist_y": "2.0",
            "output_format": "tif",
            "output_type": "all",
            "type": "writers.gdal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you include the command(s) / json string that you have used so far?

Comment: **Generating a DTM:**     
'
{
    "pipeline": [
        "E:/ground.laz",
        {
            "filename":"E:/ground.tif",
            "output_format":"tif",
            "output_type":"all",
            "grid_dist_x":"2.0",
            "grid_dist_y":"2.0",
            "type": "writers.gdal"
        }
    ]
}
'
**Writers.gdal:**
'
{
  "pipeline":[
    "E:/ground.las",
    {
      "resolution": 1,
      "radius": 15,
      "filename":"E:/ground.tif"
    }
  ]
}
'

Comment: Here's a link to [Generating a DTM](https://www.pdal.io/workshop/exercises/analysis/dtm/dtm.html).

Comment: And [Writers.gdal](https://www.pdal.io/stages/writers.gdal.html).

Answer (score 1):

The pipeline in the workshop is incorrect for PDAL 1.5+.

Follow the [Basic Example](https://www.pdal.io/stages/writers.gdal.html#basic-example) in the [writers.gdal](https://www.pdal.io/stages/writers.gdal.html) document.

```
{
  "resolution": 10,
  "radius": 14.14,
  "filename":"outputfile.tif"
}
```

Comment: the Basic Example in the writers.gdal document generates a 6 band raster instead of a single band i.e DEM/DTM.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the fourth band (idw) using [writers.gdal](https://pdal.io/stages/writers.gdal.html). The other bands are statistics for the cell calculated using the points that lie within a radius. If you only want to see the idw band, just change the symbology in the GIS software that you are using.